# Separate trouble into pieces

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I'm trying to say that trouble consists of several pieces. I'm trying to look for the best word to use instead **piece of trouble**. So far I was thinking of these: *share, fraction, part, portion, dose, segment, quantum, chunk, lump, bit, and snip*

Maybe **piece** is the best choice?

Comment: As a native English speaker, I don't know what you mean when you say that "trouble consists of several pieces".

Comment: To solve a problem, break it up|divide it  into smaller pieces. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22divide%20a%20problem%20into%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: I would say "break it up into smaller problems" or "(more) manageable problems."

Comment: You can divide your trouble into **troublets**, the better to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, "trouble" is often an uncountable noun that can be measured in quantities but not portions.  A common expression for a large amount of trouble is "a *heap*"

> You're in a **heap of trouble** young man.  Go to your room!

Similarly you can say "a (great) *deal* of trouble", or "a *lot* of trouble".

Of course this is simply convention.  Once you get into the realm of *creative writing* there's no need to be so literal.

> That's a **hefty bite** of trouble you've taken son.  I think you're going to choke on it.
>
> She felt like a whole **army of troubles** had encamped on her doorstep.

One you're using metaphor, you can find creative ways to establish what a "piece of trouble" would be:

> He baked them up a **whole cake of trouble**, and made sure each of them got a **generous slice**.

You can use *any* of the words you mention in a similar way to describe some "piece" of the trouble, but you have to get creative with it.

Comment: What about a small piece of trouble?

Comment: "The entire gang had to chew on the cookie of trouble, so that even the lowest members had to choke down a few crumbs."  Ok, maybe not my best work, but you get the idea  :)

Comment: Any minor word could work?

Comment: Sure, if you're clever.  How would you phrase this in your native language?

Comment: Actually, have no idea

Answer (score 0):

You could say

> I have had my share of troubles

I never read this anywhere, but if you say

> I have had scraps of trouble

the ambiguity could mean that none of the incidents was a big deal, or it could imply some kind of fight.